# How to ensure ref.current exists before firing on click function?

Tags: reactjs

I am receiving an undefined error when trying to set canvasRef.current. I have tried many different ways to form a callback ref, but I am getting no luck. How can I wait to fire the onClick function 'handleViewStuff' AFTER canvasRef.current is not undefined?

```
const Child = (props) => {

  const canvasRef = useRef();

  const handleViewStuff = useCallback(() => {
     
    apiCall(id)
      .then((response) => {
        
        // do stuff

        return stuff;
      })
      .then((result) => {

        result.getPage().then((page) => {
        
      const canvas = canvasRef.current; 
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d'); // error is coming in here as getContext of undefined meaning canvas is undefined'

          canvas.height = 650;
          

          const renderContext = {
            canvasContext: context,
           
          };
    
          page.render(renderContext);
        
        
        });
      });

  }, []);

  return (

    <Fragment>

    <canvas ref={(e) => {canvasRef.current = e}} />

        <Button
      
          onClick={handleViewStuff}
        > 
         View Stuff

       </Button>
      
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using `if-statement`

```
...
if(canvas.current) {
  const canvas = canvasRef.current; 
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
}
```

2. Using `optional chaining`

```
...
  const canvas = canvasRef?.current; 
  const context = canvas?.getContext('2d');
```

And I found some mistakes in your code.

1. add dependencies on `useCallback`

```
const handleViewStuff = useCallback(() => {
  ...
}, [canvasRef.current]);
```

2. should use ref like this.

```
<canvas ref={canvasRef} />
```